# RewriteRule for friendly url names

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this url: **127.0.0.1/test.php?name=john.smith** that become **127.0.0.1/profile/john.smith** with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^*]+)$ test.php?name=$1 [L]
```

What I wish is remove /profile/ to simply have **127.0.0.1/john.smith**

I meet some problem to find the correct RewriteRule.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ test.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Woaw, I am impressed. This works perfectly well. A big thank-you.